# How to get all commits in a repository along with the corresponding branch name?

Tags: python-3.x, api, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I am faced with a problem of getting all commits in a repository with the branch name too along with the commit ID . While there exists one endpoint that lists all the commits (https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commits) what this API does not give is the branch name along with the commit ID . If I call the branches endpoint : /2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/refs/branches/{name} I can get only the latest commit and not all commits in the branch . To do any kind of mapping I would need to call each branch and then another loop to call each commit within a branch this causes the code to fail as I exceed the no. of requests allowed . I need some solutions to tackle this problem .

I am writing a python script that calls these two api endpoints in two loops and generating a list of lists out of this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file history option provided by bitbucket.
And Branch name by default is master unless you change it in your properties file.

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/filehistory/%7Bcommit%7D/%7Bpath%7D